# Make folders on multiple drives appear in a single folder without using symlinks

Tags: linux, mount, symbolic-link

I have directories sorted by date on different physical drives:

```
/mnt/drive1/2000
/mnt/drive1/2001
/mnt/drive2/2002
/mnt/drive3/2003
/mnt/drive4/2004
/mnt/drive4/2005
/mnt/drive5/2006
```

How can I get them to appear in a single folder, without using symbolic links?

```
/library/2000
/library/2001
/library/2002
/library/2003
/library/2004
/library/2005
/library/2006
```

Can I "mount" the folders to another folder? The reason I shy away from symlinks is because when I use applications like rsync and scp, I'd like to be able to copy to the symbolically linked directory without worrying about special flags to ensure the symlinks are followed.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just remount them each one in its year's folder ?

Comment: Some drives have multiple years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two options:

1) <strike>Use Hard symlinks. Rsync doesn't need special flags to traverse these, because they look like part of the filesystem.</strike> - Of course, this only works on the same filesystem, which doesn't apply.

2) A bind mount. `sudo mount -o bind /source /dest`.

Comment: Hard links are only possible on the same filesystem. Just delete your first option.

Comment: Is there any performance degradation to using a bind mount?

Comment: Not as far as I know... As with everything though, test test test!